# Alternative to Shotwell

Tags: shotwell

I have a Nikon camera and a Doro phone. On my windows 7 pc I am able to download photos from both using Piccassa with no problems.

On my Linux laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 I can download photos from my camera with no problems. However Shotwell does not recognise my Doro  phone and no icon appears when I connect it.

I understand Piccasa no longer supports linux and I cannot download it.

Is there an alternative to Shotwell  or am I doing something wrong

Comment: The phone should show up in the file manager as an external storage device. If that doesn't happen, Shotwell will certainly not recognize it. Please connect the phone and tell us what the output of `lsusb` is.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of alternatives to Shotwell, also last Picasa for linux is still available to download if you search for it.

[F-Spot](http://f-spot.org/)

[digiKam](http://www.digikam.org/)

[Gwenview](http://gwenview.sourceforge.net/)

Although it looks like your problem is like Jos said, your pc isn't recognizing your phone.